# Devise and Koala to work with Facebook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

can anyone tell me the get start with the facebook API using koala and devise. Is there any availability to get users based on the access token. I also want to know how to post it in free heroku  web hosting.

I want a nice tutorial go through this.

thanks in advace

Comment: This is not a valid SO question.

Comment: Oh I got my requirement without devise help i get it through fb_graph.  https://github.com/santhu46/fb_graph_test can any one help how to freehost it in heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i completed my task using fb_graph without need for devise. I posted it in following heroku url http://arcane-hamlet-5439.herokuapp.com

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git tutorial helps me a lot to push it into heroku